# Why must a ret2libc attack follow the order "system(),exit(),command?

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, exploit-development, glibc, stack-overflow

In a ret2libc attack, I understand that the return address can be overwritten with the address of the system command, which takes a command string as an argument. In this case, shouldn't the address of the command string come directly after the address of system()? However,most tutorials I have seen follow the format :  address of system().address of exit().address of command string.

Why is it mandatory to include the address of exit()? Will the attack still work if exit() is excluded?

Comment: You can always try excluding the exit() statement and try out? ;)

Comment: I tried excluding the address of exit() and placed the address of the command string directly after the address of system() but it doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ret2libc (and return oriented programming (ROP)) technique relies on overwriting the stack to create a new stack frame that calls the system function. This wikipedia article explains stack frames in great detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers

The stack frame dictates the order the function call and parameters are written:

`function address
return address
parameters`

So in your example you want to call `system()` with `cmdstring` and return to the `exit()` function when the `system()` call returns. So you write the following stack frame:

`system_addr
exit_addr
cmdstring_addr`

If you remove the exit address you change the stack frame to the following:

`system_addr
cmdstring_addr
existingdataonstack_aka_junk`

So now you're calling `system()` with a junk address argument and trying to return into your command string once the function completes. Which is why it fails. You can replace the `exit()` address with other data such as  `0x41414141` which will cause a `segfault` once the `system()` call completes. Or you could replace it with the address of a `pop pop ret` location and then write more stack frames underneath. This is now a `ROP` payload. Here is a basic example of how that would look on the stack:

`system_addr
poppopret_addr
cmdstring_addr
printf_addr
exit_addr
addr_of_string_to_printf`

This would allow you to print something like `You got hacked` before exiting.

Comment: In the wikipedia article the order of operations seems to be: `arguments`, `return address`, `local variables`. For return-to-libc, why is the order not then `system_addr`, `cmdstring_addr`, `exit_addr`?

Comment: @rookie When returning from the vulnerable function, `system_addr' looks like a return address, and the two others are arguments.  Control is transferred to `system()` by popping the stack, and now `exit_addr` looks like the return address and `cmdstring_addr` looks like an argument.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `exit()` is included is to terminate the program *gracefully*. If you don't have `exit()` at the end of your chain the program will either continue to run weirdly or most likely terminate with a segmentation fault. It's not mandatory to include a call to `exit()`. Ideally you will construct your exploit in such a way that afterwards the program continues to run as usual so nobody gets suspicious because their service isn't running anymore.